# A straightforward functional way to rename columns of a Deedle data frame

Tags: f#, deedle

Is there a concise functional way to rename columns of a Deedle data frame `f`?

`f.RenameColumns(...)` is usable, but mutates the data frame it is applied to, so it's a bit of a pain to make the renaming operation idempotent. I have something like `f.RenameColumns (fun c -> ( if c.IndexOf( "_" ) < 0 then c else c.Substring( 0, c.IndexOf( "_" ) ) ) + "_renamed")`, which is ugly.

What would be nice is something that creates a new frame from the input frame, like this: `Frame( f |> Frame.cols |> Series.keys |> Seq.map someRenamingFunction, f |> Frame.cols |> Series.values )` but this gets tripped up by the second part -- the type of `f |> Frame.cols |> Series.values` is not what is required by the `Frame` constructor.

How can I concisely transform `f |> Frame.cols |> Series.values` so that its result is edible by the `Frame` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine its function when used with `RenameColumns`:

```
df.RenameColumns someRenamingFunction
```

You can also use the function Frame.mapColKeys.

> Builds a new data frame whose columns are the results of applying the
>   specified function on the columns of the input data frame. The
>   function is called with the column key and object series that
>   represents the column data. 
>   [Source](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-framemodule.html)

Example:

```
type Record = {Name:string; ID:int ; Amount:int}

let data = 
    [| 
        {Name = "Joe";     ID = 51; Amount = 50};    
        {Name = "Tomas";   ID = 52; Amount = 100};  
        {Name = "Eve";     ID = 65; Amount = 20};   
    |]

let df = Frame.ofRecords data

let someRenamingFunction s =
    sprintf "%s(%i)" s s.Length

df.Format() |> printfn "%s"

let ndf = df |> Frame.mapColKeys someRenamingFunction

ndf.Format() |> printfn "%s"

df.RenameColumns someRenamingFunction

df.Format() |> printfn "%s"
```

Print:

```
     Name  ID Amount
0 -> Joe   51 50
1 -> Tomas 52 100
2 -> Eve   65 20

     Name(4) ID(2) Amount(6)
0 -> Joe     51    50
1 -> Tomas   52    100
2 -> Eve     65    20

     Name(4) ID(2) Amount(6)
0 -> Joe     51    50
1 -> Tomas   52    100
2 -> Eve     65    20
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. As usual it's just a matter of me not looking hard enough at what is available within the library, plus the function names not coinciding exactly with that I am expecting to find (although `mapColKeys` is very descriptive for what it does). If anything, I hope this question/answer starts coming up for people googling _"deedle data frame rename columns"_, as the current results are meagre.